# <input> has no value in HTML but does in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have found an `<input type="text" ...` element on a page, for which `$('thatElement').val()` and `$('thatElement')[0].value` return the value, the value is displayed in the rendered output, but there is no `value="..."` attribute on the element itself.

How can there be no value attribute in the HTML for an input element, but it still has a value and still displays its value?

Browser console:

```
> $('thatElement')[0].value
'The text that the page shows inside of the input'
> $('thatElement')[0].outerHTML
'<input autocomplete="off" type="text" readonly spellcheck="false">'
```

Comment: Depends on how you compare. Do you by any chance compare the page source code (NOT via dev tools in any browser) and the JS-evaluation? Because source code (by right-click -> show source code) will only show what comes from the server intially, which may very well have been changed since then.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @ArSeN inspect element, and even `.outerHTML` shows no value attribute

Comment: [Attributes are not the same as properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003819/what-is-the-difference-between-properties-and-attributes-in-html). The attribute only shows the initial value and (usually) never changes. The property has the current value but does not show in the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a difference between the source of a document and its DOM representation. The source file is static and won't change. The DOM *might* change. I *think* it depends on how you manipulate it.

In this example the input value is set but the DOM isn't updated: (run and inspect the result)

```js
document.querySelector('input').value = 42;
```

```html
<input />
```

In this example both the input and the DOM is updated:

```js
document.querySelector('input').setAttribute('value', 'foobar');
```

```html
<input />
```